# Merging 2 rows of related data in sql db via Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am little new to Python and very new to mysql.  I have been working on a python script to auto discover new Cisco switches and populate their data in mysql db automatically.  The script has many files but I will make it simple as I am trying to solve one particular problem.

Here is the code I need assistance with:

```
host = ['Switch1.abc.com', 'Switch2.abc.com']
while i<len(host):
    print "\n Logging into", host[i], "\n"
    #Logs in to host[i] and grabs data from switch and assigns it to variables below
    login(user, password, host[i], timeout)
    #Prints to test all variables have proper data fom host[i]
    print "DB Data: ", host[i], Pair2, Pair1_Vlan1, Pair1_Vlan2, Pair2_Vlan1, Pair2_Van2, ospf, interlink, mgmt, Env, Domain
    #Create a new entry in table with host[i] data
    updateDB.insertSQL(host[i], Pair2, Pair1_Vlan1, Pair1_Vlan2, Pair2_Vlan1, Pair2_Vlan2, ospf, interlink, mgmt, Env, Domain)


    '''
    pusdo code:
    if host2 == host1's peer
       # using UPDATE, it sets peer's vlan info 
       updateDB.updateSQL(Pair2, Pair2_Vlan1, Pair2_Vlan2, host[i])
   '''   
   i += 1
```

I statically assigned 2 switches to host variables for testing but it comes from a different function that does snmp crawl and returns any # of switches.

Here is the database looks after I run this.

```
| SW_Pair1        | SW_Pair2        | Pair1_VLAN1| Pair1_VLAN2| Pair2_VLAN1| Pair2_VLAN2| Inter | Mgmt| OSPF| Env | Domain|
|-----------------|-----------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-------|
| Switch1.abc.com | Switch2.abc.com | VLAN-111   | VLAN-333   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
| Switch2.abc.com | Switch1.abc.com | VLAN-222   | VLAN-444   | Unknown    |  Unknown   |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
```

The way these switches are setup are in pairs.  So, as you can see in table, when script logs in to host1, it gets all data that is on that host and the only thing host1 can see about host2 is its name since they are a pair.

Now when while loop finishes host1 (Switch1), it goes to host2 (switch2) and then does the same thing.  Now like host1, host2 stores all the info it has and only thing it knows about its pair is its name.

Since they are pairs, they have many identical info like domain, mgmt port etc.  The only thing I am interested in Vlans and making sure both are pairs as they have each other's name in SW_Pair1 and SW_Pair2.

So, what I would like to do is merge both rows so it looks like this:

```
| SW_Pair1        | SW_Pair2        | Pair1_VLAN1| Pair1_VLAN2| Pair2_VLAN1| Pair2_VLAN2| Inter | Mgmt| OSPF| Env | Domain|
|-----------------|-----------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-------|
| Switch1.abc.com | Switch2.abc.com | VLAN-111   | VLAN-333   | VLAN-222   |  VLAN-444  |   47  | 24  | 0.1 | Dev | abc   |
```

There are many other rows in this table so I want to make sure I over-write proper row. I don't know what is the best way of achieving this.  I tried couple things under while loop to compare pair1 and pair2 (see psudo code above) but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated as I have spend a lot of time reseaching and trying multiple things without success.

Thanks